# MVC CkFinder "System.Web.HttpException: Failed to Execute URL" Error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm using CkFinder in CkEditor image search and upload in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. In my local IIS does not any problem but in the remote server has `System.Web.HttpException: Failed to Execute URL` error when I browse images with CkFinder in CkEditor.

### Error details as follows:

Description:

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Web.HttpException: Failed to Execute URL.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to Execute URL.]
System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6.BeginExecuteUrl(String url, String method, String childHeaders, Boolean sendHeaders, Boolean addUserIndo, IntPtr token, String name, String authType, Byte[] entity, AsyncCallback cb, Object state) +2582829
   System.Web.HttpResponse.BeginExecuteUrlForEntireResponse(String pathOverride, NameValueCollection requestHeaders, AsyncCallback cb, Object state) +412
   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +192
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

### Edit:

I click Image Add button in CkEditor.

[image: 1]

Nextly I click "Browse to the server"

[image: 2]

At the moment to be calling "CkFinder6/config.ascx" file and the getting error.

[image: 3]

Comment: You need to ask a question. Please also bear in mind that questions like "Why isn't this code working?" are not accepted on StackOverflow.

Comment: (In a reply to a removed comment:) I understand this perfectly. You want to ask "why my app does not work". Great. I advise you to read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article though, because your question has no value for other developers, nor it can be answered. Asking a question is part of "How do I ask a good question?". You neither did one nor the other.

Comment: There is an error, stack trace and a solution if given. Does resolve this error will benefit the community?

Comment: The error is "0x80004005", it is a permissions problem. I changed IIS "pipeline mode" from "classic" to "integrated" to be fixed. **Also people should answer the questions he knew only!**